# How can I turn off syntax highlighting for one specific element?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

I'm editing pandoc markdown text with inline math. Since that uses underscores, vim will helpfully highlight everything after the first underscore, but there will be no matching one. 
[image]

How can I turn off highlighting for this syntax element?
In `~/.vim/syntax/markdown.vim` I find elements like

````
syn region markdownItalic start="\S\@<=\*\|\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\|\*\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownItalic start="\S\@<=_\|_\S\@=" end="\S\@<=_\|_\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownBold start="\S\@<=\*\*\|\*\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\*\|\*\*\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart,markdownItalic
syn region markdownBold start="\S\@<=__\|__\S\@=" end="\S\@<=__\|__\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart,markdownItalic
syn region markdownBoldItalic start="\S\@<=\*\*\*\|\*\*\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\*\*\|\*\*\*\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownBoldItalic start="\S\@<=___\|___\S\@=" end="\S\@<=___\|___\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownCode matchgroup=markdownCodeDelimiter start="`" end="`" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownCode matchgroup=markdownCodeDelimiter start="`` \=" end=" \=``" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
syn region markdownCode matchgroup=markdownCodeDelimiter start="^\s*```.*$" end="^\s*```\ze\s*$" keepend
````

So I tried `:hi clear markdownItalic` and the same with `markdownBold` and `markdownBoldItalic`. None of those do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `markdownItalic` syntax element is a link to `htmlItalic` (could someone elaborate what that means?), so setting `hi clear htmlItalic` does the trick for me.
The downside is that this breaks all other sort of highlighting within the region vim thinks is italic text.

Answer (score 3):

[As you've discovered](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17350/343), `markdownItalic` is a link to `htmlItalic`, which just means the former uses the highlighting configured for the latter group.

You can remove a highlight link with a command like the following:

```
:highlight link markdownItalic NONE
```

See `:help :highlight-link` for more details.